# Авторизация Keycloak React, запрос в БД

Tags: reactjs, mobx, keycloak

Мой компонент App выглядит следующим образом:

```
const App = observer(() => {
    const { keycloak, initialized } = useKeycloak()

    const { user } = useContext(Context)

    useEffect(() => {
        if (initialized && keycloak.authenticated) {
            // Если пользователь авторизован загружаем инфу по нему из БД
            keycloak.loadUserProfile().then(profile => {
                fetch(`http://localhost:8001/api/user/children/${profile.username}`)
                    .then(res => {
                        return res.json()
                    })
                    .then(resBody => {
                        const body = {
                            ...profile,
                            role: keycloak.realmAccess.roles,
                            fio: resBody[0].json_build_object.fio,
                            children: resBody[0].json_build_object.children,
                        }
                        // храним инфу в mobx
                        user.setIsAuth(true)
                        user.setUser(body)
                    })
                    .catch(error => console.log(error))
            })
        }
    }, [keycloak.authenticated])

    return (
        <div className='App'>
            <Routes>
                {publicRoutes &&
                    publicRoutes.map(({ path, Component }) => (
                        <Route key={path} path={path} element={<Component />} />
                    ))}
                {authRoutes &&
                    authRoutes.map(({ path, Component }) => (
                        <Route
                            key={path}
                            path={path}
                            element={
                                <Protect>
                                    <Component />
                                </Protect>
                            }
                        />
                    ))}
                <Route path='*' element={<div>404</div>} />
            </Routes>

        </div>
    )
})
```

Я получаю данные о пользователе из Keycloak через keycloak.loadUserProfile(), затем делаю запрос в БД, чтобы получить другие данные о пользователе и затем заношу их в стейт mobx для того чтобы далее в других компонентах и страницах не делать запрос заново, а получать их из контекста.

Вопрос в том, правильная ли это реализация? Может быть нужно создать какой-либо кастомный хук для этих целей?

Также буду благодарен за ссылки на хорошие примеры подобной реализации